# calc() function not returning percent

Tags: css, css-variables

I'm using a polyfill for CSS custom properties.

Here is my variables (everything work on modern browsers) :

```
--main-color-hue: 205;
--main-color-saturation: 73%;
--main-color-luminosity: 29%;

--main-color:       hsla(var(--main-color-hue), var(--main-color-saturation), var(--main-color-luminosity), 1);
--main-dark-color:  hsla(var(--main-color-hue), var(--main-color-saturation), calc(var(--main-color-luminosity) * 0.5), 1);
--main-light-color: hsla(var(--main-color-hue), var(--main-color-saturation), calc(var(--main-color-luminosity) * 1.5), 1);

--main-text-color:       hsl(0,100%, calc((30% - var(--main-color-luminosity))     *100)); 
--main-dark-text-color:  hsl(0,100%, calc((30% - var(--main-color-luminosity)*0.5) *100)); 
--main-light-text-color: hsl(0,100%, calc((30% - var(--main-color-luminosity)*1.5) *100));
```

With the polyfill, I get this result for `--main-text-color` :

```css
a {
background-color: red;
color: hsl(0,100%, calc((30% - 29%) * 100));
}
```

```html
<a href="#">My link</a>
```

And this result doest not work on IE10 and IE11...

Answer (score 1):

Your semantic is correct but, as mentioned at [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com/#search=calc) in the "Known Issues" tab:

"IE does not support calc() on color functions. Example: color: hsl(calc(60 * 2), 100%, 50%)."

So I believe it's not your code's fault, that "calc" it's just not working on IE